# VDM++ language semicolon

Tags: vdm++

I am reading a manual of VDM++ language. My question is this in some cases he use ";" at the end of statement and somewhere in the same statement he is not using ";".

Below is the example

```
public Top : () ==> Elem
Top() ==
return (hd stack);


if test
then OpCall()
else return FunCall()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semi-colons are separators in VDM, rather than terminators as they are in Java and C. So you need the semi-colon where two things are in sequence, such as two definitions or two statements. But you do not need the separator if there is only one thing in the "block".

So your first example *may* need the trailing semi-colon if another definition follows, but not if "Top" is the last definition in the class/module.

Your second example does not need a semi-colon after OpCall() because it is a single statement in a "then" clause. You *might* need a semi-colon after the FunCall() if this if/then/else was followed by another statement, but not otherwise.

Having said this, the VDMJ parser is forgiving and will allow spurious semi-colons in some places, even though they are strictly not required.

Comment: then how we know that where the statement end? actually i'm trying to convert vdm+ code into c++ language.
Thanks.

Comment: If you're making a VDM++/C++ translation, you have to parse the VDM++, as I assume you are doing. So a "statement" is either a single statement (with no semicolon) or a block (with semicolons between the statements, and no semicolon after the block). Similarly with definitions at the outer level, except that each sequence of definitions lies between a keyword like "types", "values", "operations" etc. If there is more than one in the sequence, you need semicolon separations; and you don't need one after the last one in the sequence.

Comment: You may also face various challenges regarding the poorly defined semantics of VDM++ compared to C++. See the first paper [here](https://sites.google.com/site/nickbattle/home/vdmj/publications/BCSWorkshopProceedings.pdf)